# Outlook desktop client does not filter away emails that don't match a search term

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a folder with ~9000 emails, all referencing various codes. I'm trying to find all the emails that reference a specific code, so that I could delete them. However, the search function is not behaving as I expect it to. Instead of making all emails that don't match the search term disappear from view, leaving me with just the matches, it instead highlights the matching emails, but leaves them buried in the noise of all the other emails that shouldn't match. This is rather useless to me. Is there a way to make it act like I described in my expectations?

I'm using the Office 365 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> leaving me with just the matches, it instead highlights the matching
> emails, but leaves them buried in the noise of all the other emails
> that shouldn't match.

Be sure, in Outlook Search Options, that you have enabled (checked) Relevant Items to the Top.

That move all matches to the top and eliminates most noise.

That is the only native way to manage the Outlook Search tool.

This method works, brings all found items to the top, and then can be further selected and deleted.

[image: Outlook Search Options]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only results containing your search fields will be displayed in the search results. If you think the search results are not expected, please narrow the search scope or add more conditions to make the search results more accurate. For more information about searching, refer to: [How to search in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da).

On the other hand, don't you want to highlight the search field?

If so, just unselect the "Highlight search terms in the results" option as shown in the below figure.

[image]